# Operation column in Debug logs

Tags: debug

What does "/ui/common/InlineEditEntitySave" under Operation column in debug logs mean? What class or trigger or page has been called for this opration to trigger?

Answer (score 2):

It's the standard "inline edit" that occurs a user views a record, double-clicks a field with the "pencil" icon, and then clicks Save. It is not related to a class, Visualforce Page, or trigger specifically, although, obviously, triggers, process builders, and so on may be called as a result of the edit.